# Does calculations take place when I assign a statement to a variable or when that variable is called

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a pandas dataframe of `1,000,000` rows which looks like this:

```
A         B     
10        20
Text      Word
...
Text_1m   Word_1m
```

I have declared 100 variables like so:

```
a = df[df['A']>50 & df['B'] == 'Word_1231']
```

I later use these variables in the Slack app as `/commands` which simply return the value of the variables.

My question is: does those 100 variables and their value gets calculated at the moment of declaration or for example when I write `print(a)`?

I come up with this question because of the high number of variables and large dataframe, if they get calculated at the point of declaration, what other methods could I use to only calculate the value of a variable when I actually use it, for example `print()`? Put everything in functions?

**UPDATE**

Does the variable `a` only gets calculated when I call the function or when I declate it?

```
def calculate():
  a = df[df['A']>50 & df['B'] == 'Word_1231']
  return a
```

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Yes, Python executes your statements as they happen. You can use a lazy data structure with a generator interface if you don't want to do the calculation on the spot. More to the point, don't try to optimize out something until it's become an actual issue. Hundreds of elements are unlikely to ever be a speed or memory issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have added an update, does this way `a` computes at the point of declaration or the call of the function?

Comment: There's no declaration in Python. Always at the call of the function. A `def` statement only creates a code object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say, because pandas can either use copies or views. The choice is presented as an implementation detail that can depend on various parameters. The only important thing is that the user should be prepared to both.

The problem is that if it is a view, at assignement point, only the references for the view are stored, while if is a a copy, the full extraction is done at the assignment point.

But the whole point is that using 100 distinct variables to do almost the same thing is an anti-pattern. The correct way is to create loops that (re-) assign the variable with the proper sub dataframe and then processes it. If you really need all the sub dataframes at the same time, for any reason, then you should store them in a container like a list or dict.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And if those 100 variables hold only numeric value, like `12314` and that's it, I assume it is not that big of a deal for computing and storing. Basically I just need to return `sum` of a particular set of parameters from the dataset, hence all of the variables store only numbers up to 10 digits. My concern was maybe that is a very bad practice but I am not sure how I should try making it better.

Comment: @JonasPalačionis That is not a memory problem but only a design one because of maintainability. If you repeat the same block of code many times and later need to change something, you will realize that DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) is better in programs...